# Expected value for a fair die game

Tags: self-study, expected-value, dice

You roll a fair die until the cumulative sum rolled so far is a multiple of 3. You get $1 for each roll. What is the expected amount you will get?

I started by finding the probability of the game ending with "i" rolls, P(i). If I have this, I can then find the expectation. P(1), the probability of the game ending in 1 turn is 1/3 as either 3 or 6 can end the game. I continued doing this for P(2), P(3), etc., by writing down the sample space. It was too cumbersome and didn't know if it would end. Is there a more structured way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a homework question. I was asked this question in an interview but I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing. Note that this policy and the [tag:self-study] tag also apply in your situation.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you mean by "a dice". The singular of "dice" is "die", so are you rolling one die or multiple ones? If a single die, what do you mean by "the sum of the values that show up"? Do you mean the cumulative sum rolled so far?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thank you for the suggestions. I have added the tag, changed the dice to die and described my approach.

Comment: At each step, the chance that the cumulative sum will be a multiple of 3 is always 1/3, no matter what the cumulative sum currently is.  Thus, you are really rolling a three-sided die until a specified side appears.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I have voted to reopen, and upvoted. Your approach makes a lot of sense. As you write, $P(1)=1/3$. Let $Q(n)$ denote the probability that the game is still ongoing after $n$ rolls. Can you give a simple formula for $Q(n)$? Can you express $P(n)$ as a function of $Q(n-1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this very complicated, but the main trick is probably to recognize that

*"independent from the current cumulative value there is a 1/3-th probability that a roll ends the game"*

Then this game has a distribution of number of dice rolls that is geometric distributed with parameter $p=1/3$ and this has an expectation value of $1/p = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

*upd* Sorry for making the solution so complicated, whereas the result is definitely true.

---

We use DiscreteMarkovProcess to model the process:

[image]

Mathematica code:

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
transferMatrix = ConstantArray[1/3, {3, 3}];
transferMatrix[[3]] = {0, 0, 1};
(transferMatrix) // MatrixForm
\[CurlyPhi] = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, transferMatrix];

VisualizeOneMarkovProcess[\[CurlyPhi]_] := 
 Graph[\[CurlyPhi], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeLabels -> 
   With[{sm = 
      MarkovProcessProperties[\[CurlyPhi], "TransitionMatrix"], 
     statesNumber = 
      Length@MarkovProcessProperties[\[CurlyPhi], 
        "InitialProbabilities"]}, 
    Flatten@Table[
      If[sm[[i, j]] != 0, DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {}], {i, 
       statesNumber}, {j, statesNumber}]], ImageSize -> Medium]

VisualizeOneMarkovProcess[\[CurlyPhi]]
```

Then we calculate the mean of the FirstPassageTime to the absorb state.

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = FirstPassageTimeDistribution[\[CurlyPhi], 3];
mypdf = PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], k]
(* \[Piecewise] 2^(-1+k) 3^-k   k>0    0    True *)

Mean[\[ScriptCapitalD]]   (* 3 *)
```

So the answer is $\color{blue}{3}$

Comment: Code-only answers are useful but not really on topic here on CV when they have contain statistical explanation or insight: consider posting your *Mathematica* solutions on the [Mathematica site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) instead.